# Fastest way to search for a string

Tags: c++, hashmap, hashtable

I have 300 strings to be stored and searched for and that most of them are identical in terms of characters and lenght. For Example i have string "ABC1","ABC2","ABC3" and so on. and another set like sample1,sample2,sample3. So i am kinda confused as of how to store them like to use an array or a hash table. My main concern is the time i take to search for a string when i need to get one out from the storage. If i use an array i will have to do a string compare on all the index for me to arrive at one. Now if i go and impliment a hash table i will have to take care of collisions(obvious) and that i will have to impliment chaining for storing identical strings.

So i am kind of looking for some suggestions weighing the pros and cons of each and arrive at the best practice

Comment: Any reason your want to implement your own container, rather than using a standard one?

Comment: Why would you *implement* a hash map?!?

Comment: Unless you need to do the comparison several thousands of times per second, using normal `std::string`, in a standard container, and just comparing them should be enough. The keyword here is *benchmarking!*

Comment: Yes.. The reason is i have a fixed memory allocated for my container.. i guess maps and other STLs allocate memory dynamically.

Comment: STL containers only allocate memory when you ADD things to them -- lookups do not involve any allocations.  So if you have a fixed set of strings, you only do fixed allocation when you initialize.  If you have a dynamic set of strings, I don't see how you can avoid dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how much your data is changing. With that I mean, if you have 300 index strings which are referencing to another string, how often does those 300 index strings change?

You can use a std::map for quick lookups, but the map will require more resource when it is created the first time (compared to a array, vector or list).

I use maps mostly for some kind of dynamic lookup tables (for example: ip to socket).

So in your case it will look like this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> my_map;
my_map["ABC1"] = "sample1";
my_map["ABC2"] = "sample2";

std::string looked_up = my_map["ABC1"];
```

Comment: i have used unordered_maps in linux. its pretty easy. But  now i am into embedded where in there are memory constraints..I am not sure about the over heads involved in using a map.. Lik

Comment: It is good practice to think ahead when doing development for embedded software. But, before spending days on writing a small-footprint implementation you should try going with STL and only optimize if you recognize that you are/will be running out of resources. But this heavily depends on what SOC you use.

Answer (score 2):

Because the keys are short tend to have a common prefix you should consider radix data structures such as the Patricia trie and Ternary Search Tree  (google these, you'll find lots of examples)   Time for searching these structures tends to be O(1) with respect to # of entries and O(n) with respect to length of the keys.  Beware, however that long strings can use lots of memory.

Search time is similar to hash maps if you don't consider collision resolution which is not a problem in a radix search.  Note that I am considering the time to compute the hash as part of the cost of a hash map.  People tend to forget it.

One downside is radix structures are not cache-friendly if your keys tend to show up in random order.   As someone mentioned, if the search time is really important: measure the performance of some alternative approaches.

Comment: I do not want to allocate memory dynamically if i have the option..Say like i have a structure and the string that i want to search is part of the structure  like...  struct details{ std::string strX}.... so its like i have to store "abc" into the structure and use the same as a key for searching makes sense..But then how much additional memory will it take if i go with a map where in my key would be th string and then the value would be inside a structure.

Comment: If your program loads the strings into a structure at startup time and no new keys are added on-the-fly  there will be no need to allocate memory AFTER the search table is built.   If you want to avoid memory allocations during startup, too, you'll have to place some severe constraints on your data (no matter which technique you use) and allocate the necessary space at compile time.